# How to get usage(progress) bar to display properly in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

```
<div class="dd">
<div class="blue" style="WIDTH:$s%">$s%</div>
<div class="green" style="WIDTH:$v%">$v%</div>
<div class="red" style="WIDTH:$g%"><br>$g%</div>
</div>
```

In FF the three different elements are displayed on a single status bar, showing the accumulation of the quantities. However, in IE, it's all messed up. I get separate bars for each element and the colors and alignment are all off.

The CSS:

```
/*These are for multiple element types on same status bar */ 
     div.dd { 
   /*position: relative; /* IE is dumb */
    display: block;                 
    float: left;     
    width: 500px; 
    height: 16px; 
    margin: 0 0 2px; 
    background: url("white3.gif"); 
    margin-left:20%; 
}

div.dd div.blue { 
    /*position: relative; */
    background: url("blue.gif"); 
    height: 16px; 
    width: 75%; 
    text-align:right; 
    display:block;
    float: left;
}
div.dd div.red { 
    /*position: relative; */
    background: url("red.gif"); 
    height: 16px; 
    width: 75%; 
    text-align:right; 
    display:block;
    float: left;
}

    div.dd div.green { 
    /*position: relative; */
    background: url("green.gif"); 
    height: 16px; 
    width: 75%; 
    text-align:right; 
    display:block;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are $s, $v and $g doing in your HTML; and the `<br>`, for that matter?

If I remove the `<br>`, and replace those $ values by actual percentages that add up to 100% it works just fine for me in IE6, except for the left margin. But that's caused by [the doubled float-margin bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html).

The way to fix that margin, according to that article, is to set the `display` property on `div.dd` to `inline`.

Speaking of which, you can remove all those `display: block` properties you're using, because the display property is ignored for floats (except by IE, to some extent, as the above bugfix demonstrates).

Comment: this is a template html file, the $ are replaced by numbers